# CSS styling hooks not applying for lightning-badge in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, slds-grid

I have the below lightning-badge component where I am trying to change the background color. The background color is not changing. What could be the issue?

HTML:

```
 <lightning-badge label={product.ProductStatus} class="new-product"></lightning-badge>
```

CSS:

```
.new-product {
    --sds-c-badge-color-background: rgb(6, 6, 155);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

the only thing i see wrong is your css property name:

`--sds-c-badge-color-background`  should be  `--slds-c-badge-color-background`

however, it could well be a copy pasta typo.

Comment: I changed it but still not working. Can you check this please? https://webcomponents.dev/edit/vUTA50otg0UimWu7SerV/src/app.css?p=stories